# Placement css, img and js of files after deploy spring mvc application

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I'm new in spring mvc, and I have some questions:

1) Can I get access to img, css and js inside WEB-INF directory from jsp page?

Folder structure is:

```
webapp
  - WEB-INF
     - css
     - js
     - img
```

2) I have the class WebMvcConfig, extending WebMvcConfigurerAdapter:

> ```
> @Configuration
> @EnableWebMvc
> @Import({BeanConfig.class, CacheConfig.class})
> public class WebMvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
> ```

```
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/css/").setCachePeriod(31556926);
        registry.addResourceHandler("/img/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/img/").setCachePeriod(31556926);
        registry.addResourceHandler("/js/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/js/").setCachePeriod(31556926);
    }   

    @Override
    public void configureDefaultServletHandling(DefaultServletHandlerConfigurer configurer) {
        configurer.enable();
    }   

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
        registry.addInterceptor(new ControllerInterceptor());
    }  

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver getInternalResourceViewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }    
    @Bean
    public ContentNegotiatingViewResolver getContentNegotiatingViewResolver() {
        ContentNegotiatingViewResolver resolver = new ContentNegotiatingViewResolver();
        ArrayList<View> defaultViews = new ArrayList<View>();
        MappingJacksonJsonView jsonView = new MappingJacksonJsonView();
        jsonView.setPrefixJson(true);
        defaultViews.add(new MappingJacksonJsonView());
        resolver.setDefaultViews(defaultViews);
        resolver.setOrder(1);
        return resolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public ControllerInterceptor getLoggingInterceptor() {
        return new ControllerInterceptor();
    }
}
```

I want to get access to folders: /resources/css, /resources/img and /resources/js,

Part of web.xml file:

> ```
> <servlet>
>     <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
>     <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
>     <init-param>
>         <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
>         <param-value>
>             org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
>         </param-value>
>     </init-param>
>     <init-param>
>         <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
>         <param-value>
>             config.WebMvcConfig
>         </param-value>
>     </init-param>
> </servlet>
> ```

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>mvc-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Folder structure is:

```
webapp
   - WEB-INF
   - resources
        - css
        - js
        - img
```

But it does not worked

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can do this.

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/css/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/css/").setCachePeriod(31556926);
```

And you have this structure

```
webapp
   - WEB-INF
   - resources
        - css
            - somefile.css
        - js
        - img
```

You would access your resources at

```
localhost:8080/context/css/somefile.css
```

will get the resource from `/resources/css/somefile.css`. Do the same for all the other resources.

Comment: Thanks, I have default controller, which disable path to resources.

Comment: @AlexandrSlabukh Are you still having problems? You can still fix that if you set the `order` property for the `ResourceHandlerRegistry` handler mapping.

Comment: How to do it in xml file where properties file is loaded.